# RewriteCond and Alias

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have defined alias that looks like this:

```
Alias /pictures/sm/ /var/www/my_site/data/_active_thumbnails/
```

Later in the VirtualHost section have:

```
DocumentRoot    /var/www/my_site/sites/www.my_site.com/htdocs

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/thumbnails/(.*)\.(jpg|JPG)    /images/stg-list-img.png [PT,L]
```

What I'm trying to do is to display /images/stg-list-img.png placeholder image only if the original image does not exist on the drive.

Right now it's replacing all the images from /thumbnails/. It looks like the RewriteCond is not aware about the Alias. Is there the way to overcome it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_FILENAME is only the full filesystem path wnen you use it with your rules in htaccess or  -- in per-virtualhost config like you have it's still just the URI.

This is mainly because Apache hasn't yet had a chance to map it to any file at this stage.

You could just add the prefix to your -f test, or all of: put your rules in , adding a Rewritebase /pictures/sm/, and changing your rule's regex...

However, your regex doesn't currently make any sense. If the Alias matters and is /pictures/sm, the rewriterule could never match with ^/thumbnails.